# ImageMagick on Docker container generated malformed PNG image

Tags: linux, docker, memory, memory-leaks, imagemagick

I'm going to try to be very specific here, so this might get long.

**Goal**: Trying to convert an SVG file into a PNG within a Docker container

**Problem**: ImageMagick is generating malformed PNG images in the container, while it's OK on a regular machine

**SVG file**: https://jsfiddle.net/ochaws/qezxnwfo/3/

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN apt-get update 
ADD . /home
CMD /bin/bash
```

**Command**: `$ convert mychart.svg mychart.png`

Result PNG on host machine:
[image]

Result PNG on container:
[image]

Not only 3/4 of the image was totally messed up, but rectangles were unfilled and lines were redrawn. I have no idea how imagemagick transforms it.

### **Things I've tried**:

**I. Checking binaries differences** comparing imagemagick's and its dependencies' binaries between host and container (ldd|md5sum) in order to get differences between binaries that might be triggering a possible bug:

On container:

```
root@73075bf64797:/var/www/html# ldd /usr/bin/convert | grep -Eo '/(usr|lib)/.*\s' | xargs md5sum | sort
015730545ba1a5ff1e0f500ffbb651d5  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.3
0a2ec219b7d2050e4c0916d1dee14853  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
24492a17e8dd9a9e853cd1cfdf5fc0a3  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.3
27ce2618cfd426b2f8eefa6536e0824c  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
2b7d964ae89f9782df099985e73c707b  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
3b053e7e77c4a5857607de25806a6e90  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3
4c659326fdbac8a684298ccba999cc5c  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
50390b2ae8aaa73c47745040f54e602f  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
65fd13ef7996608743284fc1210113f1  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
6809901459f3a5ca2c38add3190b539c  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0
724ac03acbf82b09cb490b03e1714f76  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
7444e02ab2de54f5503acd626c99d4b0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
79381074c86ff3a86f4fd442892a99b3  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
a01caee197b17c9586543a876bf6fd0a  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
a1282326e753a31f0810161768948999  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
a4566a3af75553930d970377533deb14  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
a5300acb8e2e5c04a078fa0f6949f18a  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1
ae99268b6d518fb9b24c234ccfa6f791  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
b34ed25caf9e14f71b7b41af34f1890f  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
b4cbe573b069bfd23039332e6cc113b7  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
b62a4e6888012062c60c41dea847f565  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
b880122a03e775f6f5c548167e7bf179  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6
ba7877e10828c3985c6246381569e58c  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0
c265ba007d786e5086e209e6260839ce  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6
c599b6af9146a6730ce1a35f63d0233f  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6
cacf55a898630c666e17233bbcd174f5  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblqr-1.so.0
df13a9c0be51bcb5ba09787c6594e264  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2
```

On host:

```
[0|0] /home $ ldd /usr/bin/convert | grep -Eo '/(usr|lib)/.*\s' | xargs md5sum | sort
015730545ba1a5ff1e0f500ffbb651d5  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.3
0a2ec219b7d2050e4c0916d1dee14853  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
24492a17e8dd9a9e853cd1cfdf5fc0a3  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.3
27ce2618cfd426b2f8eefa6536e0824c  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7
2b7d964ae89f9782df099985e73c707b  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
3b053e7e77c4a5857607de25806a6e90  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3
4c659326fdbac8a684298ccba999cc5c  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
50390b2ae8aaa73c47745040f54e602f  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
65fd13ef7996608743284fc1210113f1  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
6809901459f3a5ca2c38add3190b539c  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0
724ac03acbf82b09cb490b03e1714f76  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
7444e02ab2de54f5503acd626c99d4b0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
79381074c86ff3a86f4fd442892a99b3  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
a01caee197b17c9586543a876bf6fd0a  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
a1282326e753a31f0810161768948999  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
a4566a3af75553930d970377533deb14  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
a5300acb8e2e5c04a078fa0f6949f18a  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1
ae99268b6d518fb9b24c234ccfa6f791  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
b34ed25caf9e14f71b7b41af34f1890f  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
b4cbe573b069bfd23039332e6cc113b7  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
b62a4e6888012062c60c41dea847f565  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
b880122a03e775f6f5c548167e7bf179  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6
ba7877e10828c3985c6246381569e58c  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0
c265ba007d786e5086e209e6260839ce  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6
c599b6af9146a6730ce1a35f63d0233f  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6
cacf55a898630c666e17233bbcd174f5  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblqr-1.so.0
df13a9c0be51bcb5ba09787c6594e264  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblcms2.so.2
```

**Conclusion**: Binaries are **exactly the same** in both host and container, so I guess I can roll that out.

**II. Checking memory behavior** in both environments with valgrind:

On container:

```
root@b0b319995ed0:/home# valgrind --leak-check=full convert blue_charts.svg blue_charts.png
==1390== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1390== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1390== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1390== Command: convert blue_charts.svg blue_charts.png
==1390== 
==1390== 
==1390== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1390==     in use at exit: 191,228 bytes in 2,905 blocks
==1390==   total heap usage: 359,830 allocs, 356,925 frees, 146,363,268 bytes allocated
==1390== 
==1390== 288 (256 direct, 32 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 85 of 129
==1390==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1390==    by 0x628E8ED: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.10.1)
==1390==    by 0x628F096: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.10.1)
==1390==    by 0x6290377: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.10.1)
==1390==    by 0x62959C3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.10.1)
==1390==    by 0x8011DE7: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.7)
==1390==    by 0x8012BBB: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.7)
==1390==    by 0x8010802: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.7)
==1390==    by 0x80114C4: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.7)
==1390==    by 0x801508C: XML_ParseBuffer (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.7)
==1390==    by 0x6294B42: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.10.1)
==1390==    by 0x6294F75: FcConfigParseAndLoad (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1.10.1)
==1390== 
==1390== 912 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 100 of 129
==1390==    at 0x4C31B25: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1390==    by 0x40134A6: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:286)
==1390==    by 0x40134A6: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:530)
==1390==    by 0x7ADA227: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:627)
==1390==    by 0x7ADA227: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:644)
==1390==    by 0x76A1209: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==1390==    by 0x76980DD: GOMP_parallel (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0)
==1390==    by 0x4F5A1D0: SetImageOpacity (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.3.0.0)
==1390==    by 0x4E98930: SetImageAlphaChannel (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.3.0.0)
==1390==    by 0x4EFAD4D: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.3.0.0)
==1390==    by 0x4F0465B: DrawPrimitive (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.3.0.0)
==1390==    by 0x4F0674C: DrawImage (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.3.0.0)
==1390==    by 0xDA1636F: ???
==1390==    by 0x4EC098E: ReadImage (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.3.0.0)
==1390== 
==1390== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1390==    definitely lost: 256 bytes in 1 blocks
==1390==    indirectly lost: 32 bytes in 1 blocks
==1390==      possibly lost: 912 bytes in 3 blocks
==1390==    still reachable: 190,028 bytes in 2,900 blocks
==1390==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1390== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==1390== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==1390== 
==1390== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1390== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

On host:

```
[0|0] /home $ valgrind --leak-check=full convert blue_charts.svg blue_charts_local.png 
==17898== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17898== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17898== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17898== Command: convert blue_charts.svg blue_charts_local.png
==17898== 
==17898== 
==17898== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17898==     in use at exit: 98,349 bytes in 23 blocks
==17898==   total heap usage: 4,253 allocs, 4,230 frees, 6,204,037 bytes allocated
==17898== 
==17898== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17898==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17898==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17898==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17898==    still reachable: 98,349 bytes in 23 blocks
==17898==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17898== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==17898== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==17898== 
==17898== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17898== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Conclusion**: imagemagick on container is taking an insane amount of memory (146,363,268 bytes) if compared to host (6,204,037 bytes). Also, there's several memory leaks with libfontconfig, and libMagickCore-6.Q16 when running on a container, plus I have no idea where those are (can't run GDB nor strace within Docker) and I'm not very motivated to go down that road since same binaries behave weirdly being the container the only difference.

Sorry for big text, but I ran out of options to debug that. Any help?

Comment: Did you check if the same fonts are installed on both machines?

Comment: Imagemagick can use its own internal SVG renderer (MSVG/XML) or the RSVG delegate or Inkscape (in order of increasing quality and accuracy). One possibility is that you are only using MSVG on Docker, but are using one of the other renderers externally on your separate system. Check to see what delegates are installed on your system and on Docker. `convert -list format` should show you what renderer is being used on the SVG returned line.

Comment: There's also a lot of errors/issues within the SVG file. Clip-paths that don't resolve, conflicts of style (e.g. `style="fill: gray;" fill="none"`), missing required attributes, &tc. How are the SVG's generated?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I'll respond to each later today

Comment: @fmw42, this is the output of 'convert -list format | grep -i svg': MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer
      SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.4)
     SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (XML 2.9.4)
Both environments...

Comment: You are using the Imagemagick internal MSVG/XML renderer for SVG file. You might get better results by installing the RSVG delegate into Imagemagick or just installing Inkscape so that Imagemagick would find it and use it automatically. What is the version and date of Imagemagick? `convert -version` and what delegates does it show? Do both your Imagemagick versions use MSVG/XML. Likely one system uses it and the other uses RSVG or Inkscape. Or it could be differences in Imagemagick versions.

Comment: @dlemstra, I just did `fc-list  | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | tr -d ':' | xargs -n 1 -I {}  docker cp {} quirky_snyder:{}` on my host, where quirky_snyder is my container's name. Tried to generate it again, but nothing =(, it's not a font thing

Comment: @fmw42, I did notice that both host and container are using same binaries: `convert -version` (container): Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114
`convert -version` (host): Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114.
As I mentioned in my question, I pointed `/etc/apt/sources.list` to the same address in both container and host.

Comment: But are the delegates the same with the same version numbers. Do both systems use MSVG/XML for SVG and are they both using the same version of libpng?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. The image is malformed while using Docker because the container **haven't Inkscape installed**. Obviously Imagemagic uses Inkscape to convert SVG if it's on the path.

So adding the following line to `Dockerfile` resolves the problem:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install inkscape
```

There are [more information](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=33100) on the Imagemagic forum.